# how to send data in two table by using one form in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have created two table first one users and second one is user_datas but data is going in only users table not in user_datas table

->This is UsersController add function Code

public function add()
    {

```
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data,['associated'=>'UserDatas']);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)){

            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    //$states = $this->Users->States->find('list', ['keyField'=>'id', 'valueField'=>'state_name','limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize',['user']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost what is the relationship between the Users table and the Userdatas table (hasOne or HasMany). Controller code :

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data,['associated'=>'UserDatas']);
    if ($this->Users->save($user,['associated'=>'UserDatas'])){
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
//$states = $this->Users->States->find('list', ['keyField'=>'id', 'valueField'=>'state_name','limit' => 200]);
$this->set(compact('user'));
$this->set('_serialize',['user']);
```

This will work if the input name in the form used in collecting the data conforms to the cakePHP table relationship in the view. Eg:

```
$this->Form->create($article);
// Article inputs.
echo $this->Form->input('title');
// Author inputs (belongsTo)
echo $this->Form->input('author.id');
echo $this->Form->input('author.first_name');
echo $this->Form->input('author.last_name');
// Author profile (belongsTo + hasOne)
echo $this->Form->input('author.profile.id');
echo $this->Form->input('author.profile.username');
// Tags inputs (belongsToMany)
echo $this->Form->input('tags.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('tags.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('tags.1.id');
echo $this->Form->input('tags.1.name');
// Multiple select element for belongsToMany
echo $this->Form->input('tags._ids', [
'type' => 'select',
'multiple' => true,
'options' => $tagList,
]);
// Inputs for the joint table (articles_tags)
echo $this->Form->input('tags.0._joinData.starred');
echo $this->Form->input('tags.1._joinData.starred');
// Comments inputs (hasMany)
echo $this->Form->input('comments.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('comments.0.comment');
```